# SOAP UI gives Internal Server Error but Fiddler Says Invalid Header

Tags: http, soapui, fiddler, webservice-client

I have a SOAP b2b web service to consume. I'm trying to understand the basic elements of the call and eventually consume it without an app.config / wsdl import and will be using c#.

I imported the wsdl to SOAP UI entered some dummy values for the request data and typed in the password to the request properties. I returned a 500 error, details restricted to local machines.

1 strange aside properties say Authentication Type: No Authorization but without the correct credential I do get a 401.

The Raw SOAP UI Call

```
GET https://b2b.example.com/yyyb2b/zzz.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: b2b.example.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://www.example.com/yyy/GDDA"
Content-Length: 424
Host: b2b.example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

So I tried to replicate the call in fiddler to see if I could get any better information:

The headers there:

```
POST /yyyb2b/zzz.asmx HTTP/1.1: 
Host: b2b.example.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 419
SOAPAction: "http://www.example.com/yyy/GDDA"
Authentication: Basic base64(username:Password)
```

Fiddler returns a 302 (found) and then a 400 saying bad request - Invalid Header

I tried removing POST /yyyb2b/zzz.asmx HTTP/1.1: as the 'bad header' and got redirected to sign into the gui portion of the web app. The other possible difference I see is the method of authentication.

Why am I getting different errors?

Comment: Is your authentication header literally base64username:base64password or is it: base64(username:password)? ... for clarity there - does your Basic header contain a colon in the final, b64 encoded string?

Comment: yes the colon is included in one base 64 string i converted using the fiddler text wizard which was format username:password per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: Be careful putting too much faith into an https response through Fiddler. Fiddlers installs an intermediate certificate that can cause authorization issues.

Comment: If you look at msc you can find it easy, it's called something like "DoNotTrust" ..if it uses that cert it messes things up.